# Calcular a diferença de altura com CSS

Tags: css, css3

Existe uma forma de eu fazer o **código** abaixo, que está em **JQuery**, mas com **CSS**?

```
 $(document).scroll(function() {

    if (  $(this).scrollTop() > $(window).height() ) {

        $("section#topo").css("height", "10vh");
        $("section#topo").css("background", "#999");

    } else {

        $("section#topo").css("height", "7vh");
        $("section#topo").css("background", "none");

    }

});
```

A ideia seria algo do tipo:

```
<style>

    calc (body.scrollTop > window.height) {
        section#topo {
            height: "10vh";
            background: #999;
        }
    }

    calc (body.scrollTop <= window.height) {
        section#topo {
            height: "7vh";
            background: none;
        }
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Não entendo o porque dos negativos, é uma pergunta válida. Mas respondendo: não, dessa forma não. Por mais simples que seja você terá que utilizar um pouco de JS.

Comment: @RenanGomes, Obrigado pelo apoio. Eu não tenho muita experiência com CSS. Mas imaginei que existisse uma forma de contornar esse problema! Pesquisei muito antes de postar a pergunta e não encontrei nada. Quem sabe alguém aqui j[a passou por isso e tenha encontrado uma solução. Sobre os negativos, liga não! Só servem para atrapalhar os que tem menos conhecimento e não conseguem sequer formular sua pergunta!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Da para resolver metade do problema só com CSS, talvez possa te ajudar de alguma forma.

Como no jQuery da para perceber que vc quer que a qualquer movimento do *scroll* a seção do topo mude, eu imagino que essa seção deve estar colada no topo da página...

Nesse exemplo estou usando `position:sticky` com valor negativo no pai, e com valor positivo no filho, assim vc consegue um efeito bem interessante. **Só com CSS!**

<sup>Já sobre trocar uma cor de `background` só com CSS ao fazer *scroll*, isso ainda não é possível, pois o CSS não detecta eventos de *scroll*, mas o js sim...</sup>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 200vh;
}

.box {
  height: 105px;
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: -50px;
}
.box .teste {
  position: sticky;
  top: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span class="teste">
    teste
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hugo. Interessante tua solução. Mas acho que vai ser melhor manter o jQuery mesmo. Mas mesmo assim, pelo esforço em ajudar, vou aceitar a tua solução! Mais uma vez! muito obrigado pelo apoio!

Comment: @CarlosRocha valeu ai meu caro! Realmente na sia situação só com jQuery mesmo, pois o CSS não detecta movimentos no scroll, ai não é possível colocar ou retirar classes ou propriedades com esse tipo de interação. O que vc  pode fazer é tratar isso com JavaScript puro, sem usar o jQuery. Esse tipo de código não é complexo de fazer com JS puro não, e vc não precisa importar o jQuery só pra isso. Vlw